# Why does Class.newInstance always throw an exception?

Tags: java, exception, reflection, constructor, runtime-error

I want to define a custom class loader to load my own class at run-time.

However, `Class.newInstance` always fails even if I defined a zero-argument constructor.

The exception message is:

**java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class Hello can not access a member of class Test with modifiers "public"**

Why?

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    private Map<String, Class<?>> classes = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();

    public String toString() {
        return CustomClassLoader.class.getName();
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        if (classes.containsKey(name)) {
            return classes.get(name);
        }

        byte[] classData;

        try {
            classData = loadClassData(name);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException("Class [" + name
                    + "] could not be found", e);
        }

        Class<?> c = defineClass(name, classData, 0, classData.length);
        resolveClass(c);
        classes.put(name, c);

        return c;
    }

    private byte[] loadClassData(String name) throws IOException {
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(name.replace(".", "/")
                        + ".class"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int i;

        while ((i = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(i);
        }

        in.close();
        byte[] classData = out.toByteArray();
        out.close();

        return classData;
    }
}

class Test
{
    public Test()
    {}

    public void Hello()
    {}
}

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            CustomClassLoader loader = new CustomClassLoader();
            Class<?> c = loader.findClass("Test"); // OK!
            Object o = c.newInstance(); // ALWAYS FAIL!
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { 
            String s = e.getMessage();
            // s is "java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class Hello can not access"
            // " a member of class Test with modifiers "public""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the stack trace of the exception say? Have you read it? Because the information you're looking for is right in there. Right now, the stack trace is hidden because you catch Exception and ignore it. Don't do that.

Comment: My suspicion is that the problem involves the fact that the `Test` class is loaded by a downstream class loader from where you try to create a new instance.

Comment: My guess is that `Test` and `Hello` are in different packages or in the default package.

Comment: @PeterLawrey No, they're all in the same file (and in the default package).

Comment: Never use the default package.

Comment: @JBNizet I believe that using the non-default package would result in the same problem for this specific case. Checking now. (And it's fine to use it for toy examples.)

Comment: @JBNizet Identical behavior with a non-default package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that your `Test` class is declared with default (package) scope, but at runtime, your `Hello` and `Test` classes are in different packages.

The name (unique identifier) of a class in Java is a combination of the fully-qualified class name *and the class loader that loaded it*:

> At run time, a class or interface is determined not by its name alone, but by a pair: its binary name (§4.2.1) and its defining class loader. Each such class or interface belongs to a single run-time package. The run-time package of a class or interface is determined by the package name and defining class loader of the class or interface. [(JVMS 5.3)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3)

In this case, the `Test` class is being loaded by a downstream class loader, and so its (default) package is not considered to be the same (default) package that `Hello` (loaded by the system class loader) is in. Therefore, you don't have access to the constructor since the class itself is not public.

This example will work if you either make `Test` a separate public top-level class or use reflection to make it available.

Comment: in my case, the inner class was not static

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the class public:

```
public class Test { ... }
```

Or, get a reference to the constructor and make it accessible:

```
Constructor<?> constructor = c.getConstructor();
constructor.setAccessible(true);
Object o = constructor.newInstance();
```

Comment: Problem isn't the constructor, it's the class itself.

Comment: wow, indeed, this works but do you know why this is requried? Can I somehow modify the class so that the already `public` constructor doesn't have to be made public _again_?